# How to remove " from the whole table?

Tags: string, matlab, quotation-marks, matlab-table

Lets get a simple table that has 2 columns `A` and `B`. Values of this table look like:

```
"ABCD" "123"
"EFGH" "456"
"IJKL" "789"
```

And here I need to remove all `""`, so I will get only values between `""`. Is it some property of table, that it gives strings into `""`? I am not able to remove them. Is there just a different approach to work with strings in tables?

Comment: It's just a property of strings and how they're represented in tables. They quotes are not actually in the string value, they're only there when you display the table. Why do you want them removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a string array to make that table and hence the `"`s.
Use [**`categorical`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html) to get rid of them in your table.

An example:

```
%Assuming you have the data in the form of a string array, so creating a string array
S= string({'ABCD' '123';'EFGH' '456'; 'IJKL' '789'})

%S = 
%
%  3×2 string array
%
%    "ABCD"    "123"
%    "EFGH"    "456"
%    "IJKL"    "789"

T = table(categorical(S(:,1)),categorical(S(:,2)))

%T =
%
%  3×2 table
%
%    Var1    Var2
%    ____    ____
%
%    ABCD    123 
%    EFGH    456 
%    IJKL    789
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought i would need to loop over all rows, but this is really easy and fast way to change it :)

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: We've been stuck over an hour trying to figure this out .Thank you so much!